# When defining a derived class, why is the base class marked "public?"

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between private, public and protected inheritance in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c)

One of the examples in my lecture notes is

```
class TransportShip : public GameUnit {
    int capacity;

    public:
         ...
}
```

Why do we need the "public" modifier before the name of the base class?  What would it mean if it wasn't there?

Comment: Read the chapter in your C++ book about public, protected and private inheritance.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html

Comment: We don't actually have a textbook -_- Thanks for the link though

Comment: @badatmath Then get one!

Comment: Books like "Teach Yourself C++ in 21 Days" is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would mean that the base class is private.

With a class, the base and all members are private by default.  With a struct, the base and all members are public by default.

If the base was private, then only members of the class would be able to access members of the base.